# Laravel - way to get 3 only columns from db and print it in SELECT form

Tags: php, laravel, forms, select

I wanted to get 3 values from table which are : id, place and row.

```
$places = Place::where('occupied', '=', 0)->pluck('place', 'id'); // it gets only 2 values I know.
```

Then I want to print it in Laravel form SELECT. So I passed it into view and tried to show it in SELECT:

```
{{Form::select('id_place', $places , null ,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
```

It shows something like this:

```
<option value="1">1</option>
[...]
<option value="25">25</option>
```

Where option value is an ID and thing between brackets is place.

Is there any way to print data from db something like:

```
<option value="1">Place: 1, Row: 1</option>
```

?

Im using Laravel forms.
Please help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you are trying as

```php
$places = Place::where('occupied', 0)->select('id', 'place', 'row')->get();
```

```
@foreach($places as $place)
    <option value={{ $place->id}}>Place: {{$place->place}}, Row: {{ $place->row }}>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Will it be a problem if I combine laravel forms with regular html?

Comment: I don't think so you can have the entire select as a regular html

Comment: Does it work or does it cause any issues - mixing regular html with laravel forms?